# MYSQL GROUP BY not grouping

Tags: php, mysql

HI I am trying to group some results by a visit_id, however it just doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code.

```
  SELECT url1 FROM pages GROUP BY visit_id ORDER BY timedate
```

Here is my database structure

```
 id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`url` text NOT NULL,
`time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`timedate` datetime NOT NULL,
`visit_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`url1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`page_time` time NOT NULL
```

The code works it just doesn't seem to group by id

Comment: Can you provide data and result?

Comment: share some sample data and results

Comment: I guess you want to order the results and have the rows with same `visit_id` grouped together. If yes, try `SELECT visit_id, url1 FROM pages ORDER BY  visit_id, timedate`

Comment: You do know that a non-aggregated column (`url1`) that's not part of the `group by` will give you indeterminate values?

Comment: You are using `GROUP BY` incorrectly. Every other DBMS will reject your statement. Read this: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html to understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a guess.  The guess is that you want all `url1` for a given `visit_id` "grouped" together.  If so, use `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT visit_id, group_concat(url1 separator ', ' order by timedate)
FROM pages
GROUP BY visit_id
```

I also included `visit_id` in the `select` clause so you can see which visit corresponds to which pages.  If you want a unique list, then use `group_concat(distinct url1 . . .)`.